# Flask top-level code executing every route navigation

Tags: python-3.x, flask, import, python-module

All top-level code in our Flask app.py, and its imported modules with top-level code, are executing every time a route is visited. By either our misunderstanding of Flask's app.py execution under a web server, and/or our poorly implemented modules, we are expecting the top-level code in app.py and all its imported modules to run once.

Setup (none of which can be changed):

- Flask: 1.1.1
- Python: 3.6.8
- Deployed to Apache web server (Linux): 2.2.15

We've verified all top-level app/import code is running on every page change (.route) by looking at logs and changing config file data (between page navigation) that is displayed on the UI and read by imported modules.
We see this log message, from "security.py" below, every page change: audit_logger.info("Processing for NONE Security!")

I suspect our app.py, and its imported modules, are implemented in an incorrect way. Maybe we shouldn't have ANY top-level code in our imported modules? Here's are edited snippets of our code:

**app.py**

```
#!/path/to/python3

from logger import app_logger, audit_logger
#... lots of similar imports here
from security import security_data

# register ppmh Flask app name
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
now = datetime.now()
date_now = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# handle exception handler for catch error
app.register_error_handler(500, internal_server_error)
app.register_error_handler(404, page_not_found)
app.register_error_handler(500, handle_http_exception)
app.register_error_handler(500, handle_exception)

# Set variables for all templates
@app.context_processor
def g_vars():
    return dict(userdata=curr_user,
                date=date_now,
                securityinfo=security_data)

app.secret_key = 'dev'

app_logger.info("[app.py appLogger test]")
audit_logger.info("[app.py auditLogger test]")

# set rules for Flask webpages
app.add_url_rule('/myprojectname/css/<path:filename>', endpoint='css', view_func=app.send_static_file)
app.add_url_rule('/myprojectname/js/<path:filename>', endpoint='js', view_func=app.send_static_file)
#... lots of similar add_url_rule() here
app.add_url_rule('/myprojectname/cgi-bin/index.cgi/landing', endpoint='landing')
app.add_url_rule('/prodnames/cgi-bin/index.cgi/main', endpoint='main')

# build a blueprint for Flask webpages
app.register_blueprint(landing_bp)
#... lots of similar register_blueprint() here
app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**logger.py**

```
#!/path/to/python3

import logging
from logging.handlers TimedRotatingFileHandler
from config import config_logAppPath, config_logAuditPath
from user import curr_user

app_logger = None
audit_logger = None

class custom_formatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.user_name = curr_user.name
        return super(custom_formatter, self).format(record)

def create_logger(log_file, logname, level=logging.INFO):
    formatter = custom_formatter('[%(asctime)s] (%(user_name)s) (%(levelname)s) %(filename)s/%(lineno)d: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # rotate log file every Sundays
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, when='W0', backupCount=0)
    handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(logname)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

audit_logger = create_logger(config_logAuditPath, "audit", logging.INFO)
app_logger = create_logger(config_logAppPath, "app", logging.INFO)
app_logger.info("In logger.py")
```

**security.py**

```
#!/path/to/python3

from config import config_securityText
from logger import audit_logger

banner_bg_color = "securityUnset"
sec_text = config_securityText

if sec_text == "NONE":
    banner_bg_color = "securityNone"
    audit_logger.info("Processing for NONE Security!")
elif sec_text == "HEAVY":
    banner_bg_color = "securityHEAVY"
    audit_logger.info("Processing for HEAVY Security!")
else:
    sec_text = "UNSET"
    audit_logger.info("NOT Processing Security!")

class SecurityClass:
    text = sec_text
    bg_color = banner_bg_color

security_data = SecurityClass()
```

**user.py**

```
#!/path/to/python3

import os
from config import config_userVar

class UserClass:
    id = 'USER-ID-UNSET'
    name = 'USER-NAME-UNSET'
    id_num = 'USER-IDNUM-UNSET'
    role = 'USER-ROLE-UNSET'

curr_user = None

# Get user's info from server environment var and set user data
def process_userenv():
    global curr_user
    
    try:
        id = os.environ[config_userVar]
    except Exception as e:
        return

    # process user env here
    curr_user.id = id
    # etc...

curr_user = UserClass()
process_userenv()
```

**index.cgi**

```
#!/opt/global/webservices/apache/pyenv/prodnames_pyenv/bin/python3

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
import app as ui

class ScriptNameStripper(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

ui.app = ScriptNameStripper(ui.app)
CGIHandler().run(ui.app)
```

**screen_landing.py. (screen_main.py has similar .route)**

```
#!/path/to/python3

import traceback
from config import config_htmlDir, config_landingScreenDescription
from logger import app_logger
from flask import (Blueprint, render_template)

landing_bp = Blueprint("landing_bp", __name__, template_folder=config_htmlDir)

# initial index page to load the page
@landing_bp.route("/landing")
def landing():
    return render_template('screen_landing.html', landingscreen_description=config_landingScreenDescription)
```